# Find duplicate values in objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sorting

I've been trying to work out a problem I'm having. I have an array with objects in it, like this:

```
var array = [
  {
    name: "Steven Smith",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 35
  },
  {
    name: "Hannah Reed",
    Country: "Scottland",
    Age: 23
  },
  {
    name: "Steven Smith",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 35
  },
  {
    name: "Robert Landley",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 84
  },
  {
    name: "Steven Smith",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 35
  },
  {
    name: "Robert Landley",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 84
  }
];
```

I want to get the objects that have duplicate values in them and based on what values to search for. I.e , I want to get the object that has a duplicate value "name" and "age" but nog "country" so I will end up with:

```
[
  {
    name: "Steven Smith",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 35
  },
  {
    name: "Steven Smith",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 35
  },
  {
    name: "Robert Landley",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 84
  },
  {
    name: "Steven Smith",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 35
  },
  {
    name: "Robert Landley",
    Country: "England",
    Age: 84
  }
];
```

If been trying to do

```
array.forEach(function(name, age){
  if(array.name == name || array.age == age){
    console.log(the result)
}
})
```

But that only checks if the values of the object is equal to them self.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does `array` need to retain its original values or is it mutable?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-duplicates

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use 2 `reduce`. The first one is to group the array. The second one is to include only the group with more than 1 elements.

```js
var array = [{"name":"Steven Smith","Country":"England","Age":35},{"name":"Hannah Reed","Country":"Scottland","Age":23},{"name":"Steven Smith","Country":"England","Age":35},{"name":"Robert Landley","Country":"England","Age":84},{"name":"Steven Smith","Country":"England","Age":35},{"name":"Robert Landley","Country":"England","Age":84}]

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.name + '-' + v.Age;
  c[k] = c[k] || [];
  c[k].push(v);
  return c;
}, {})).reduce((c, v) => v.length > 1 ? c.concat(v) : c, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is awesome! Very elegant, mark this as answer, thank you so much :)

Comment: how do I only get the distinct elements at the very end?

Answer (score 9):

I'm a little late to the party but this might help someone who's facing the same problem, as it is, I believe, an easier to understand solution:

```
const duplicates = [];
array.forEach((el, i) => {
  array.forEach((element, index) => {
    if (i === index) return null;
    if (element.name === el.name && element.Age === el.Age) {
      if (!duplicates.includes(el)) duplicates.push(el);
    }
  });
});
console.log("duplicates", duplicates);
```

Two things might be tricky to understand:

- with forEach you can provide a second argument that will be an index. This is to make sure we don't compare the same two array entries with each other (if (i === index) return null; -> to abort the forEach)
- !duplicates.includes ("if not duplicates includes) checks before adding an element to the duplicates array if it's already there. Since {} === {} is false in JS, this will not be a problem with "equal" objects already in the duplicates array, but will simply avoid adding the same element twice in one forEach loop

Edit:
An even nicer solution would be this:

```
const duplicates = array
    .map((el, i) => {
        return array.find((element, index) => {
            if (i !== index && element.name === el.name && element.Age === el.Age) {
                return el
            }
        })
    })
    .filter(Boolean)
console.log("duplicates:", duplicates)
```

It has no side effects and all logic is in one if statement. The filter is needed to sort out undefined instances.

Comment: You're very welcome @NileshSutar. I just added a nicer solution, after reviewing this post.

Answer (score 4):

Try below snippet. It loops array through it's own elements (inner loop). 1st `if` condition checks for same element (we do not want that in output), 2nd `if` does the required condition match to identify any duplicate object.

```js
var array = [
 {
  name: "Steven Smith",
  Country: "England",
  Age: 35
 },
 {
  name: "Hannah Reed",
  Country: "Scottland",
  Age: 23
 },
 {
  name: "Steven Smith",
  Country: "England",
  Age: 35
 },
 {
  name: "Robert Landley",
  Country: "England",
  Age: 84
 },
 {
  name: "Steven Smith",
  Country: "England",
  Age: 35
 },
 {
  name: "Robert Landley",
  Country: "England",
  Age: 84
 }
];

for(let obj of array){
 for(let ele of array){
  if(obj==ele)
   continue;
  if(ele.name===obj.name && ele.age===obj.age){
   console.log(obj);
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer I came up now:

```js
   
let result = [];

for(let item of array)
{
    for(let checkingItem of array)
    {
      if(array.indexOf(item) != array.indexOf(checkingItem) &&
        (item.name == checkingItem.name || item.Age == checkingItem.Age))
      {
        if(result.indexOf(checkingItem) == -1)
        {
          result.push(checkingItem);
        }

      }
   }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative solution, which I will point out the

```js
let array      = getData();                       // sets up data array
let duplicates = array.filter(duplicatesOnly);    // filter out duplicates

console.log( duplicates );                        // output to console



/* ============================================================================= */


// Returns true/false based on a duplicate object being found   
function duplicatesOnly(v1, i1, self) {
  let ndx = self.findIndex(function(v2, i2) {
    // make sure not looking at the same object (using index to verify)
    // use JSON.stringify for object comparison
    return (i1 != i2 && JSON.stringify(v1) == JSON.stringify(v2))
  })
  return i1 != ndx && ndx != -1
}


// Use function hoisting to place trivial code at the bottom of example
function getData() {
  return [{
      name: "Steven Smith",
      Country: "England",
      Age: 35
    },
    {
      name: "Hannah Reed",
      Country: "Scottland",
      Age: 23
    },
    {
      name: "Steven Smith",
      Country: "England",
      Age: 35
    },
    {
      name: "Robert Landley",
      Country: "England",
      Age: 84
    },
    {
      name: "Steven Smith",
      Country: "England",
      Age: 35
    },
    {
      name: "Robert Landley",
      Country: "England",
      Age: 84
    }
  ];
}
```

### Benefits

- Heart of code is 3 lines
- Code is clear
- Easy to maintain

### Costs

- Performance

  - `JSON.stringify` is being performed on two objects on each iteration (very expensive)
  - Complexity: O(N^2) -- the bigger the array, the slower it may become

### Notes

---

- `JSON.stringify` may create the string based on key order, so even if objects have the same keys/values, the order may be a factor when comparing the objects -- this could be seen as a benefit or a cost
- This is an example of using `filter` and `findIndex` the concentration was not on making it efficient.  It could be improved by using caching and performing `JSON.stringify` once, or avoiding it altogether with something more customized.