# Creating Array of objects from multiple objects in other array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I’ve got to email people in my list who has appointments tomorrow,
however when I’m writing the the subject of email I want to know who has more than one appointment tomorrow so I can configure the subject. 
Also I don’t want to send multiple emails at once. I want to send one email saying you’ve got either an appointment or you’ve got multiple appointment tomorrow. (it would be also great to know the id’s of those appointment.)

So I've got the following:

```
AllAppointments: [
    {
        id: 23,
        name: "John",
        email: "John@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 3,
        time: "morning"
    }, {
        id: 17,
        name: "Alex",
        email: "Alex @domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 3,
        time: "morning"
    },


    {
        id: 22,
        name: "Bob",
        email: "Bob@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 5,
        time: "morning"
    }, {
        id: 35,
        name: "John",
        email: "John@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 4,
        time: "afternoon"
    }

]
```

I want to get these

```
MultipleAppointments : [

        {
            ids :[23,35],
            name : John,
            email : John@domain.com,
            appointment_date : tomorrow,
            appointment_categories: [ 3, 5  ]
        }
]

singleAppointments : [ 

        { 
            id: 17,
            name : “Alex",
            email : “Alex@domain.com",
            appointment_date : tomorrow,
            appointment_category:  3,
            time: “morning"
        },


        { 
            id: 22,
            name : “Bob",
            email : “Bob@domain.com",
            appointment_date : tomorrow,
            appointment_categories:  5,
             time: “morning"
        }


]
```

Comment: nice idea, what have you tried?

Comment: In `MultipleAppointments`, shouldn't the `id` be `22`?

Comment: @JackBashford good that you mentioned. fixed it

Comment: @NinaScholz I've tried something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840157/find-duplicate-values-in-objects-with-javascript) but this only gives me an array of multiple objects, I'm not sure how to get the other array.  I'm also not sure if that's the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Start by telling where you store this data. Mongodb? mysql? memory?

Then change the way of thinking. What you need to know is which email you send more than 1 notification, and not who has how many meetings. Instead of 2 one-dimensional tables, I suggest you one multidimensional:

```
mails: {
 'John@domain.com': [
{
        id: 23,
        name: "John",
        email: "John@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 3,
        time: "morning"
    },  {
        id: 35,
        name: "John",
        email: "John@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 4,
        time: "afternoon"
    }
]
'Alex@domain.com': [{
        id: 17,
        name: "Alex",
        email: "Alex@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 3,
        time: "morning"
    }
]
'Bob@domain.com': [{
        id: 22,
        name: "Bob",
        email: "Bob@domain.com",
        appointment_date: tomorrow,
        appointment_category: 5,
        time: "morning"
    }]
}
```

And such a thing very easy to create.

```
let mails = {};
AllAppointments.forEach(one=> {
  if(!mails[one.email])
    mails[one.email] = [];
  mails[one.email].push(one)
})
for(let email in mails)
  sendMail(mails[email])
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks man I see your point. I'm using mysql and use lambda. I see if I can change the way I sort things.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just give the answer here, I'm going to walk you through how I would solve it. It helps to break down what you want to do into smaller steps, and to think of the high-level operations that you want to do separately from the concrete data types that you're working on.

- First, you want group together some objects based on a key that they have in common
- Second, you want to separate groups that only contain 1 object from groups that contain multiple objects
- Third, you want to combine all of the objects in each "multiple appointments" group into a single new object.

The first step is a common problem, and many utility libraries provide a `groupBy` function to do it. `groupBy` takes as arguments an array of objects and a function from each object to a string, and returns an array of arrays of objects. Objects for which the provided function returned the same value will be placed in the same array together. For your case, you would call `groupBy` like this:

```
const groupedAppointments = groupBy(appointments, appointment => appointment.name);
```

Trying to implement `groupBy` for yourself is a good learning exercise. As a hint, try using a `for` loop or [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Now, we have an array of arrays of objects, like this:

```
[
  [{
    id: 23,
    name: "John",
    email: "John@domain.com",
    appointment_date: tomorrow,
    appointment_category: 3,
    time: "morning"
  }, {
    id: 35,
    name: "John",
    email: "John@domain.com",
    appointment_date: tomorrow,
    appointment_category: 4,
    time: "afternoon"
  }],
  [{
    id: 17,
    name: "Alex",
    email: "Alex @domain.com",
    appointment_date: tomorrow,
    appointment_category: 3,
    time: "morning"
  }],
  [{
    id: 22,
    name: "Bob",
    email: "Bob@domain.com",
    appointment_date: tomorrow,
    appointment_category: 5,
    time: "morning"
  }]
]
```

We want to separate out the inner arrays, and make one variable hold all of the single appointments, and another variable hold all of the multiple appointments. JavaScript has a built-in method for working with arrays like this called [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Filter takes a "tester" function and applies it to each object in the array, and returns a new array containing all of the values for which the tester returned `true`. So we can use this to make two arrays, one containing groups with only one item in them, and another containing groups with more than one item in them:

```
const singleGroups = groupedAppointments.filter(group => group.length === 1);
const multipleGroups = groupedAppointments.filter(group => group.length > 1);
```

Now, `singleGroups` is still an array of arrays of appointments, with each inner array containing exactly one item. It looks like this:

```
[
  [{
    id: 17,
    name: "Alex",
    email: "Alex @domain.com",
    appointment_date: tomorrow,
    appointment_category: 3,
    time: "morning"
  }],
  [{
    id: 22,
    name: "Bob",
    email: "Bob@domain.com",
    appointment_date: tomorrow,
    appointment_category: 5,
    time: "morning"
  }]
]
```

We want to replace each inner array with the one item it contains. When you want to transform every item in an array in the same way, you can use the built-in [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. This takes a function which transforms a single element, and applies it to every item in the array. So to "ungroup" single items, we would use it like this:

```
const singleAppointments = singleGroups.map(group => group[0]);
```

Now, `singleAppointments` contains what you want, an array of the appointments that only happen once:

```
[{
  id: 17,
  name: "Alex",
  email: "Alex @domain.com",
  appointment_date: tomorrow,
  appointment_category: 3,
  time: "morning"
}, {
  id: 22,
  name: "Bob",
  email: "Bob@domain.com",
  appointment_date: tomorrow,
  appointment_category: 5,
  time: "morning"
}]
```

Finally, we need to turn all of the groups of appointments from our `multipleGroups` array into the "MultipleAppointments"-shaped objects that you have in your question. This means we have an array of arrays, and we want an array of objects, where each inner array is turned into an object, which is a perfect case for using `Array.map` again:

```
const multipleAppointments = multipleGroups.map(groupToMultipleAppointment);

function groupToMultipleAppointment(group) {
  // ???
}
```

Now all that's left is to implement `groupToMultipleAppointment`, which takes an array of appointments like this:

```
[{
  id: 23,
  name: "John",
  email: "John@domain.com",
  appointment_date: tomorrow,
  appointment_category: 3,
  time: "morning"
}, {
  id: 35,
  name: "John",
  email: "John@domain.com",
  appointment_date: tomorrow,
  appointment_category: 4,
  time: "afternoon"
}]
```

and returns an object like this:

```
{
  ids:[23, 35],
  name: John,
  email: John@domain.com,
  appointment_date: tomorrow,
  appointment_categories: [3, 5]
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of `groupToMultipleAppointment` to you; I'd recommend using a `for` loop or `Array.reduce`.

---

So in all, here's the code I'm suggesting, with some sections left open for you to fill out yourself:

```
const groupedAppointments = groupBy(appointments, appointment => appointment.name);

const singleGroups = groupedAppointments.filter(group => group.length === 1);
const multipleGroups = groupedAppointments.filter(group => group.length > 1);

const singleAppointments = singleGroups.map(group => group[0]);

const multipleAppointments = multipleGroups.map(groupToMultipleAppointment);

function groupToMultipleAppointment(group) {
  // ???
  // `group` is an array. Use `reduce` or a `for` loop to make a new object out of it.
}

function groupBy(array, getKeyForArray) {
  // ???
  // getKeyForArray is a function which takes an item from `array` and returns a string

  // use a `for` loop or `reduce` to make a new array where 
  // objects with the same key are grouped together.
}
```

Comment: Wow man thanks a lot, this is great. I'll give it a go and comeback to you.

Comment: can you please explain your first line of cods   I'm stuck there `groupBy(appointments, appointment => appointment.name)`  where did you get `appointment` ? when I try this with groupBy function I get one `"undefined: {"`obj key with no grouping. when I try  `groupBy(appointments, 'name')` I get the groups with the names as keys like `"John": {[.. ,..]}, "Alex":{[..]}` .

Comment: `appointment => appointment.name` is an ES6 arrow function, and is the same as `function (appointment) { return appointment.name; }`. The `groupBy` function should take a function as an argument, and use it to match up all of the items in the array that it's given by key.